# Email not sending for newsletter in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to add few images in the newsletter email template. I kept the image in `skin/frontend/default/blank/images/`

In the email template I have given as:

```
<img src="{{skin url="images/image01.png" _area='frontend'}}" width="550" height="8" alt="">
```

When I add the image(the above code) in the email template, email not sending. What I am doing wrong? Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version are you using? Please remove the inappropriate tags. Was the mail sent before your customizations?

Comment: Is logging enabled? Is there anything in `var/log` or `var/report`?

Comment: @feeela - Magento-1.7, yes, email was being sent before customization

Comment: @Tim - Nothing new inside var/log and var/report

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the images?

Comment: yeah I have set the permission to 777. Any clues why email is not sending?? Is there any manual way ? ie, <img src="/skin/frontend/default/blank/images/" which is also not working?

Comment: If you really only have changed the template, I got not clue why the email is not sending. Just changing a template doesn't affect the functionality of the Magento models. Are you sure yyou haven't made any other changes on Magento or haven't installed any extensions recently?

Comment: @feela I made a new template and added appropriate codes for that in config.xml and subscriber.php. The email displaying {{var store.getFrontendName()}} . and the email send if I remove the <img> and  {{store url=""}}.

Comment: Is it possible to give the path directly ie, something like; 'http://www.XXXXXX..com/skin/frontend/default/blank/images/image01.png'